# Is it possible to have an air leak from the ductwork?

Tags: leak, ducts, crawlspace

I live in a townhome condo, occupying the third and fourth floor of the building. The indoor AC unit is on my second floor and the ductwork is in the space between the ceiling of the first floor and the floor of the second floor. Waterpipes run in that space as well. I have noticed very weak air supply from 2-3 vents on the second floor and very cold water when i turn on the tap. Water temperature normalizes after about 20-30 seconds. If i am on the second floor and unhook one of the air ducts, put a towel inside it (basically blocking the air supply through this duct), i can feel air coming out of the floor opening where the vent should be (but the duct is blocked by the towel). Does this indicate that some of the ductwork may have come apart and causing cold air to leak inside the "crawl" space between floors? I have also noticed that one particular spot of the second floor hardwood is always warm during the winter (when logically the heat is on).

Edit-providing extra information:
Thank you all for the answers. I believe i will have to call a HVAC specialist to run a video camera and see inside. I wanted to clarify something in my original post - the building has 4 floors. First two are occupied by a different residents. The third and fourth floors of the building are the two floors from my condo-in yellow. Therefore my first floor is the 3rd floor of the building and my second floor is the 4th floor of the building. The space between my two floors is in red. That is where the duct work is. Unfortunately, there is no access to that space from either of my two floors. It is about 2-3 feet deep and i can reach inside it only through the AC vents floor openings (on my second floor).  The flooring is hardwood planks all throughout the place. The indoor AC unit sits on my second floor and ductwork is bellow it. The closest vents are actually blowing the weakest. The warm spot is closest to the AC unit. Nearby is my washer and dryer without hardwood planks bellow them. If the camera determines colapsed, unhooked or ripped duct, i will have to cut through the floor sheathing and find a small child to crawl in there to patch the work. [image: s]

Comment: yes, it is possible ... your description indicates that it is likely

Comment: Is it possible to have an air leak from the ductwork? - Not only is it possible, but with the shoddy work I've seen lately, it is highly probable.

Comment: I am confused you occupy the 3rd and 4th floor but weak air flow on the 2nd floor.  If this is a problem of open vents on the 3rd floor and your system is isolated from the others this will fix the weak flow on the 4th. If all the vents are open the ones with the longest length would have the least flow if the sizes were the same. The mechanical chase may actually have a fan to push air through the mechanical spaces lots of possibilities, try adjusting or reducing the flow on your 3rd floor rooms and see if that fixes 4th floor (this is quite common in multi story residential)

Comment: Yes. A new house I bought in Houston in 1980 had mismatched the supply duct by 2" to the AC/furnace in the attic , and left it . So there was a 2 X 18 inch leak drawing in attic air. I found it about the first month the AC was on.

Comment: The warm spot is probably very close to the problem area, so if you remember where it is, your search area should be quite small.  @EdBeal  Think OP meant his second floor, the fourth, not the second floor of the building.

Comment: Tie a rope to the small child when he goes into the duct work. She may have so much fun in there that it may be your only way of getting him out. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your assessment of the problem is very likely since ducts can come apart especially if work has been done on the system or on the plumbing. Check with the maintenance department for the building since this is probably required before doing any extensive investigation. You can get AC companies to run a video camera through the ducts to see if they are breached. I have had this done when ducts under the slab had rusted through and dust was coming out of the registers.

Comment: Yep, like your answer, let's diagnose this properly and develop an appropriate fix.   I think the OP is pretty close to getting already. +

Comment: You might be able to rent a video camera on a long stiff cable and save some money.